# Advanced search module for forum in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, forum

I just took over a Drupal-based website in which I implemented a forum. Now I need to add an advanced search tool. But I haven’t found out how. Could you help me do it? Like are there any new plugins I need to download?

Answer (score 0):

If you want any way of advanced search you can study [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). There are many integration modules for Drupal and Solr. For example, you can use [Apache Solr Search](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr). I don’t use neither this module, nor Drupal itself, but Solr is a very good solution for indexing and searching.